# MongoDB repository save() do the insert instead of update

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am writing a PUT request API with spring and mongodb. But the save() inserts a new object instead of update the current one.

```
@Document("Test")
public class Expense {

    @Field(name = "name")
    private String expenseName;
    @Field(name = "category")
    private ExpenseCategory expenseCategory;
    @Field(name = "amount")
    private BigDecimal expenseAmount;

    public Expense( String expenseName, ExpenseCategory expenseCategory, BigDecimal expenseAmount) {
        this.expenseName = expenseName;
        this.expenseCategory = expenseCategory;
        this.expenseAmount = expenseAmount;
    }

    public String getExpenseName() {
        return expenseName;
    }

    public void setExpenseName(String expenseName) {
        this.expenseName = expenseName;
    }

    public ExpenseCategory getExpenseCategory() {
        return expenseCategory;
    }

    public void setExpenseCategory(ExpenseCategory expenseCategory) {
        this.expenseCategory = expenseCategory;
    }

    public BigDecimal getExpenseAmount() {
        return expenseAmount;
    }

    public void setExpenseAmount(BigDecimal expenseAmount) {
        this.expenseAmount = expenseAmount;
    }
}
```

This is my reporsitory class

```
public interface ExpenseRepository extends MongoRepository<Expense, String> {
}
```

This is my Service class which shows how to update the class.

```
@Service
public class ExpenseService {
    private final ExpenseRepository expenseRepository;

    public ExpenseService(ExpenseRepository expenseRepository) {
        this.expenseRepository = expenseRepository;
    }

    public void updateExpense(String id, Expense expense){
        Expense savedExpense = expenseRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(
                        String.format("Cannot Find Expense by ID %s", id)));

        savedExpense.setExpenseName(expense.getExpenseName());
        savedExpense.setExpenseAmount(expense.getExpenseAmount());
        savedExpense.setExpenseCategory(expense.getExpenseCategory());

        expenseRepository.save(savedExpense);
    }
}
```

This is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/expense")
public class ExpenseController {

    private final ExpenseService expenseService;

    public ExpenseController(ExpenseService expenseService) {
        this.expenseService = expenseService;
    }
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> updateExpense(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Expense expense){
        expenseService.updateExpense(id, expense);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

As shown in mongodb compass, mongodb auto generates an _id field for every object. So I do not define a id field or use @id annotation to define a primary for the collection. However, in the service class,  expenseRepository.findById(id) retrieves the desired object and update it. Why does save() do the insert instead of update? Many thanks.
[image]

Comment: You will need to map the id, else the framework has no way to determine if it was saved or not. You can use the default `_id` field for this or a dedicated business key.

Comment: How to use the default _id? I also believe it is caused by the id field but I cannot solve the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As I thought expenseRepository.findById(id) retrieves the desired object so it would update the data. Yet it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work because while saving you need to id in the object so Spring Data Mongo can determine if it is an existing one. You have no `@Id` field so it will always be treated as a new object. Just add a field named `id` of type `String` to your `Expense` and it will be mapped to the `_id` field. This is explained in the documentation (which I suggest you read). https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.id-handling

Answer (score 0):

JPA Can't find the existing entry as no id field id set. You need to add an id field and set generation type to auto.

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But since I am using swagger codegen and it doesn't support the id keyword. So i am wondering if there any other way to fix it.